# Maximum call stack size exceeded without deep calling and too many variables

Tags: angular, variables, stack, max, call

```
newCaption:string;
noDuplicate(bookmark:any):void{

  this.preferences.bookmarks.forEach(element => {
    if (element.caption==bookmark.caption){
      this.alertService.warning("Caption is duplicate!");

      if (!element.caption.includes('.')){
        element.caption=bookmark.caption +'.'+'1';
      }else {
        let captionDigitPart = element.caption.substring(element.caption.indexOf('.')+ 1 );
        let captionFirstPart = element.caption.substring(0, element.caption.indexOf("."));
        let captionDigitPart_To_int=parseInt(captionDigitPart);
        captionDigitPart_To_int++;
        this.newCaption=captionFirstPart+'.'+captionDigitPart_To_int.toString();
      }

    }

  });
  this.noDuplicate(this.newCaption);
}
```

This is my code , I faced `ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Would you please help me?

Regards.

Comment: Remove `this.noDuplicate(this.newCaption);`.

Comment: I need it as recursive! so I cant remove the last line!

Comment: Where's your **termination condition**? You need something like `if(termination_condition) return;` to exit.